# Unicode display issues (UnicodeEncodeError) via "heroku run python"

Tags: python, unicode, heroku

If I connect to a Heroku worker dyno with `heroku run` (e.g. `heroku run python` for an interactive Python session), any attempt to display Unicode characters via this results in a `UnicodeEncodeError`

Locally:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jun 25 2011, 05:09:01) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print u'\xa3'
£
```

Via `heroku run`:

```
$ heroku run python
Running python attached to terminal... up, run.1
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 31 2011, 16:22:04) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print u'\xa3'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa3' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>>
```

Now, if I `heroku run bash` and use `echo` to try to display things, all seems fine (except my local choice of font!):

```
$ heroku run bash
Running bash attached to terminal... up, run.2
~ $ echo -e "\xa3"
?
```

I assume I'm doing something wrong / missing something, but somewhat lost as to what, or further lines of investigation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this will fix your problem:

```
$ heroku config:set LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

or, if after you try to run that, heroku complains that you need to supply the app parameter:

```
$ heroku config:set LANG=en_US.UTF-8 -a <app_name>
```

Comment: This is default on all new Heroku Python apps now :)

Comment: Oh, as a function of the buildpack?

Comment: This helped so much. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issues.  The problem appears to be that, when it is not outputting to a terminal, Python 2 chooses ascii as the default encoding for the print statement.  There are ways around this, including the complex but accurate method [described here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PrintFails).  There are similar methods scattered around the net.

However, there is an easier, but deprecated, solution.  This happens to be the one I use, which consists of inserting this at the beginning of your program:

```
reload(sys) 
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

This forces print to use the utf-8 default encoding rather than ascii, and should, hopefully, fix your problem.

Comment: Alas the solution you describe doesn't seem to work for me, but the link seems highly relevant, thanks!

Comment: It may not work in the interpreter - I am away from my system and not able to check - but it ought to work if you try it in a script?

Answer (score 3):

None of the above worked but this did:

heroku config:add PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8

This is one of the answers to this question here:

[UnicodeEncodeError only when running as a cron job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932406/unicodeencodeerror-only-when-running-as-a-cron-job/11762169#11762169)

unfortunately it wasn't the accepted answer and that question is marked as a dup so I'm reposting here.