# UnicodeEncodeError only when running as a cron job

Tags: python, unicode, cron

My program works right in the commandline, but when I run it as a cron job it crashes on the error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character
u'\xa7' in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)
```

It crashes on the statement

```
print title
```

Why this is happening only when the app runs as a cron job? How could this be fixed?

I tried (with no help):

```
print unicode(title)
```

Python is 2.7

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492483/setting-the-correct-encoding-when-piping-stdout-in-python

Comment: I think it's the same issue; Python 2 uses Unicode when stdout is a terminal but not when it's a pipe (as it would be in a cron job).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Aside: This is a common problem; as such this is probably a duplicate question.*

The default encoding on 2.7 is `ascii`.
You need to provide an encoding for your program's output.
A common encoding to use is 'utf8'.

So you'd do instead:

```
print title.encode('utf8')
```

---

Here's one way to check the default encoding:

```
import sys

sys.getdefaultencoding()
# -> 'ascii'
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but why this doesn't work only when the app runs as a cron job?

Comment: ...difficult say based on provided information. You may be passing different input, for one. Whether or not it works isn't the issue. As a responsible programmer you should care about your code working with non-ascii characters.

Comment: Actually the string has been taken from the SQlite database. It was of type TEXT, so encoded as UTF-8 http://sqlite.org/datatype3.html. Maybe Python changed it when it was combined with another strings via "%s %s" % (s1, s2)

Comment: Ok, so *decode* it to Unicode when you get it from db; e.g. `'mystring'.decode('utf8')`. Then encode on output as mentioned above. And, yes, Python 2.7 does automatic conversion to Unicode when strings are combined. So you don't need to decode in that case, but it would be clearer if you did.

Comment: @bernie: It does automatic conversion *with the `ascii` codec*. It's not just clearer to decode it, it's really the only sane way to avoid bugs.

Comment: @xralf: it is different with cron job probably because it is run as a different user or in a non-interactive shell, where the `LANG` variable is not set. Check the value of `os.environ.get('LANG')` and the value for `sys.stdout.encoding`.

Comment: `>>> import os, sys
>>> os.environ.get("LANG")
'en_US.UTF-8'
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'UTF-8'`

Answer (score 98):

Nah, you can have it simpler. Just define [PYTHONIOENCODING](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html?highlight=unicode%20environment%20variable#envvar-PYTHONIOENCODING) before executing this script. Like this:

```
PATH=<your path>
MAILTO=someone@somewhere
PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8

* * * * * /run/your/script
```

Comment: Indeed this is the correct answer. Cool! :)

Comment: If I could I'd give you +2. This shit's been messing with my head!

Comment: What he said...  here I am, two years later, and this saved lots of keyboards from being smashed.

Comment: This should be accepted answer. @xralf Could you update it?

Comment: Holy crap thanks so much! I've been going nuts for a couple of hours trying to figure out what the heck.

Comment: don't forget "export PYTHONIOENCODING"

Comment: @Thierry that's crontab, not a bash script.